# Mongodb restrict access on collections level

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a backend system using MongoDB. Now I want to restrict access on certain numbers of database collections to this system. For example I have `users`, `admin_users`, `pageviews` and I want this system to be able to read and write only `admin_users` and `pageviews` collections but no read or write access on `users` colection. Is there any ways to do so?

Comment: Are you looking to restrict certain `mongod` instances to only be able to r/w certain collections within a database?

Comment: I'm not database admin, so my understanding about mongod instances is not very good. I want to add a new database user to db who can only read or write certain numbers of collections.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for `user based` solutions here. Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is [not yet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) any built in way (as of version 2.4) to provide access-control at the collection level. Mongo's ACLs go to the Database only. To do what you want you will have to move that `users` collection to a different database.

Comment: May want to edit this as current versions *do* support this.

Answer (score 3):

They have added collection-access ACLs, see here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/